# Simple server to client syncing

Tags: git, svn, synchronization

I have a setup where I have my web server that hosts a mod pack for a game that I'm going to have a handful of friends play and I need a way for them to very easily download any changes or updates I make to the mod pack.

I tried looking at SVN and GIT but I can't make heads or tails of them to make them work the way I want.

For GIT, every client I can find is at least 15MB and requires a major install to Windows. Which won't work. I just want a small standalone program that can pull down the updates/changes for them.

As for SVN. I recall Garry's mod used it and it worked great. But I spent several hours looking at it's documentation and not only would I have to set up something complex on the server, but on the client side, I can't even figure out how to make it pull from the server.

Does anyone know of a simple system I can use so that when friends want to update their mod pack to match my current one on the server, they can simply open the update program and it download/replace/delete any files that don't match the sever-side copy?

Comment: Git is a tool for versioning code, not for syncing files. I think you are talking more than a service like Dropbox, aren't you?

Comment: A bit more complicated than syncing files. Dropbox simply won't do the job. I have a mod pack hosted on the server, if people don't have an *identical* modpack on their client, they can't connect to the server. I need a tool that will always keep their mod pack identical to the server's mod pack so that they can connect.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to eventually figure out how to use SVN (Subversion) to do what I want.
Using subversion I can now push out changes to users easily by them having a small command-line version that does a svn checkout against my server and I can just maintain the package from the server end.